# got ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python, streamlit

So i make a streamlit app and implemented some math formula

```
import streamlit as st

st.title("SISTEM PERSAMAAN LINEAR DUA VARIABEL")
st.subheader("Persamaan 1: ax+by=c")
a = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel a")
b = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel b")
c = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel c")
st.subheader("Persamaan 2: px+qy=r")
p = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel p")
q = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel q")
r = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel r")
x = (c*q-r*b)/(a*q-p*b)
st.write(x)
st.caption("Note: AI KAKURU akan mencari variabel x dengan metode eliminasi lalu mencari variabel y dengan metode subtitusi")
```

it work properly using vanilla python, any idea?

so i want to implement some math formula, 2 variabel linear or something, i don't know what is proper english translate for it. It works properly when i use vanilla python, but when i write it in streamlit. it  doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like you put in values of `a`, `b`, `p`, and `q` where `a*q-p*b` gives 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `number_input` is `0`. Hence, when you first start the app, `c, q, r, b, a, q, p, b` is all `0`. It would be quite obvious to see that `(a*q-p*b)` is `0`, and hence it will result a Zero Division Error.

A solution to this is to add an if statement to check if the value of `(a*q-p*b)` is `0`. Refer to the code below.

```py
import streamlit as st

st.title("SISTEM PERSAMAAN LINEAR DUA VARIABEL")
st.subheader("Persamaan 1: ax+by=c")
a = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel a")
b = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel b")
c = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel c")
st.subheader("Persamaan 2: px+qy=r")
p = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel p")
q = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel q")
r = st.number_input("Masukan Nilai Variabel r")
if a*q-b*p == 0:
    st.write("Tidak ada solusi")
else:
    x = (c*q-r*b)/(a*q-p*b)
    st.write(x)
st.caption("Note: AI KAKURU akan mencari variabel x dengan metode eliminasi lalu mencari variabel y dengan metode subtitusi")
```